# Magento admin controller not working

Tags: magento, controller, admin

I'm new to magento and facing a problem in executing admin controller. Here is what I've done.

### Mailchimp/mailchimpmodule/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <depends>
            <!-- no dependencies -->
        </depends>
    </Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule>
</modules>
<global>
    <models />
    <blocks />
    <resources />
    <extraconfig />
    <helpers>
        <mailchimpmodule>
            <class>Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule_Helper</class>
        </mailchimpmodule>
    </helpers>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <foo_bar before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule_Adminhtml</foo_bar>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mailchimpmodule>
                <file>mailchimp.xml</file>
            </mailchimpmodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>       
</frontend> 
</config>
```

### Mailchimp/mailchimpmodule/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <mailchimpmodule module="mailchimpmodule" translate="title">
        <title>Mailchimp</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <settings module="mailchimpmodule" translate="title">
                <title>Settings</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/settings/index</action>
            </settings>
        </children>
    </mailchimpmodule>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <settings translate="title" module="mailchimpmodule">
                    <title>Mailchimp</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <index translate="title">
                            <title>Settings</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        </index>
                    </children>
                </settings>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

### Mailchimp/mailchimpmodule/controllers/adminhtml/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule_Adminhtml_SettingsController extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{  
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
            ->_addContent(
            $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('mailchimp_mailchimpmodule/adminhtml_mailchimpmodule')
            ->setTemplate('mailchimp/form.phtml'))
            ->renderLayout();       
}   
}
```

I can see MailChimp->Settings option in admin but when I click it, it shows 404 not found. Here is the URL that is getting called:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/settings/index/key/efdd74577eb9cbb46237c3803bc4e29c/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the admin/routers section. Where you have `foo_bar` should be your module name.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule_Adminhtml</Mailchimp_Mailchimpmodule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Also, your controllers/adminhtml/IndexController.php should be in a folder with a capital 'A', like controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php.